# Is this a proper use of dynamic keyword for returning JSON data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

In my Controller, I have an action that returns JSON data as such:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AjaxJson(){
    var ret = new List<dynamic>();

    ret.Add(new{
        Make = "Honda",
        Year = 2011,
    });

    ret.Add(new{
        Make = "BMW",
        Fun = true
    });    

    return Json(new { json = ret }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'm a bit concern about the use of `dynamic` keyword because the items in the list is actually anonymous type. But there is noway to create a list of anonymous type.

My second question (not as important) is that if I return my JSON data as array. on the client, to get to `Honda`, I have to reference it this way: `data.json[0].Make`

But I want be able to do it this way: `data.json.MyWeekdayCar.Make`

I know that if I return JSON data as object (controller action listed later), I can reference `Honda` with `data.json.MyWeekdayCar.Make`, but I'll lose the ability to get its length with `data.json.length`. Is there a way to get the best of both world - able to use `data.json.MyWeekdayCar.Make` and count the number of objects on client side?

Controller to return JSON data as object:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AjaxJson(){
    var ret = new{
        MyWeekdayCar = new{
            Make = "Honda",
            Year = 2011
        },
        MyWeekendCar = new{
            Make = "BMW",
            Fun = true
        },
        length = 2 // this makes client side data.json.length work, but it doesn't feel normal.
    };

    return Json(new { json = ret }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**EDIT**

Are there side effects or unintended problems for using a list of dynamic with anonymous objects?

Comment: At first glance I would say no, however your example looks quite contrived. Is there something specific you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Roysvork, I would like to return JSON data to the client side and on the client, I would like to be able to do all of the followings: `data.json.MyWeekendCar.Make`, `data.json.length` and `data.json[0].Make`. The goal is to make the data more flexible for frontend developers to work with.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Is there are also a requirement that prevents you from strongly typing your classes on the server side?

Comment: There's no requirement on server side to use strongly typed classes, but I "think" to meet the frontend needs, my best bet will be anonymous types or dynamics. Or am I wrong on that?

Comment: I usually use anonymous types combined with an `object[]` for throwaway ops (like building a small set of JSON for a particular purpose). If you are going to regularly reuse the structure, then a strongly typed class is a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer you first question there is not specifically anything wrong with using dynamic in the way that you are doing.

You will not be able to achieve exactly what you want without jumping through some hoops, but there are a couple of options available to you:

**Option 1:** You can write server side code looking something like this:

```
var honda = new { Make = "Honda", Year = "2011" };
var bmw = new { Make = "Bmw", Fun = true };
var array = new dynamic[] { honda, bmw };

var ret = new
{
    Cars = array,
    Length = array.Length,
    MyWeekDayCar = honda, 
    MyWeekendCar = bmw
};
```

Then you can use this as follows in your javascript (not quite what you want but close):

```
data.json.MyWeekendCar.Make, 
data.json.Cars.Length
data.json.Cars[0].Make
```

The downside to this approach is that you have to be very specific on the server side, and so it may be a bit inflexible. But it does involve the least work.

**Option 2:** Leave server side code as it is but without the length property:

```
var ret = new {
    MyWeekdayCar = new{
        Make = "Honda",
        Year = 2011
    },
    MyWeekendCar = new{
        Make = "BMW",
        Fun = true
    }
};
```

Then create class in javascript as a wrapper for your data that allows you to use it in the way you would want, for example:

```
CarsClass.prototype = Array.prototype;   // Inherit from array type for length and other functions
function CarsClass(json) {   
    var that = this;   // very important... but you'll need to research this yourself ;)

    for (var key in json)   // loop around all the properties in the object
    {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
            that[key] = json[key];   // copy each property to our new object
            that.push(json[key]);    // add each property to our internal array
        }
    }    
}

var cars = new CarsClass(  // This is just dummy data, you would use your json
{ 
    MyWeekdayCar : { Make: 'Honda', Year: '2011' },
    MyWeekendCar : { Make: 'BMW', Fun: true },
    AnotherCar: { Make: 'Skoda', FuelEfficient: true} // flexible!
});

alert(cars.MyWeekendCar.Make); // 'BMW'
alert(cars.length); // 3
alert(cars[0].Make); // 'Honda'
alert(cars[2].FuelEfficient); // True
```

You can see this working in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m49h5/

As you can see in this approach, you could add more cars on the server side and they would get picked up by the javascript class. Of course this approach would need to be more clever if you are then adding\removing cars on the client side. If you do need this then let me know and I can advise further

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your first option does exactly what I needed. Also, there's no need for the `Length` property in `ret` since `Cars` in `ret` is array and on client side, `data.json.Cars.length` will work (lower case L). Thank you much!

Comment: Also, the length for `Cars` is dynamic but the named ones `MyWeekendCar` or `MyWeekdayCar` are static. So to resize array, I found this code that works. http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/csharp/1.htm

Comment: I found a built-in function to do that too. `Array.Resize(ref arr, new_size)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. The second option is much cooler and more flexible so you should definately check it out too ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the best of both worlds, and your json format doesn't update regularly check out the JSON C# Class Generator: http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/

Every time you update your json format you can regenerate the classes for the frontend devs to use.

On the front end they can use the json.net libraries to deserialize your json into your generated classes as follows:

```
Car a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Car> (json);
```

If this doesn't meet your requirements, the next best solution I'm aware of is to use the dynamic object as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the best of both world - able to use `data.json.MyWeekdayCar.Make` and count the number of objects on client side?

Not with anonymous types.  You're creating a single object of an anonymous type with two properties: `MyWeekdayCar` and  `MyWeekendCar` which are *two different* anonymous types.

So you don't *have* a collection of ojects, you have *one* object with *two* properties, all of which are different types.  You'd have to add a `length` property when creating the objects.

What you *could* try is creating a `Dictionary` instead of a plain array:

```
var ret = new Dictionary<string,dynamic>();

ret.Add("MyWekedayCar",new{
    Make = "Honda",
    Year = 2011,
});

ret.Add("MyWeekendCar",new{
    Make = "BMW",
    Fun = true
});
```

Then I *think* you could access it as:

```
data.json.["MyWeekdayCar"].Make
data.json.length
```

Although to be honest I don't know enough about JSON/JavaScript and dictionaries to know if this works.  If it doesn't I'll remove it from my answer.